# How to fix an Error in get(".Random.seed" using mice package

Tags: r, r-mice

I am trying to do impute some data using random forest using the `mice` package but it throws an error. Why?

```
library(mice)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
```

- `Random forest` will be the `best fit to impute this particular data`
- `[31] mice.impute.rf`

## Use `mice` function produces an error

```
imputed_data <- mice(data, m = 5, method = "rf")
```

> Error in get(".Random.seed", envir = globalenv(), mode = "integer", inherits = FALSE):object '.Random.seed' of mode 'integer' was not found

```
summary(imputed_data)
```

> Error in summary(imputed_data) : object 'imputed_data' not found

This is when I run into my error and I have no clue how to fix it.  If anyone can help me, and explain what this means in the most basic terms, I would greatly appreciate it. I posted the error message after the tried to do the impute random forest.

Comment: What version of R are you running? What if you run `set.seed(101)` (or any random integer) before you try calling `mice()`. You should avoid copy/pasting a worksheet or tutorial or whatever the first part of your question is. Just focus on the specific problem you are having and make a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the problem. Just copy/pasting the entire text leaves a lot of irrelevant noise in the question.

Comment: I have the most updated version. Sorry, I included all the work, I didn't want to leave anything out. I didn't copy and paste anything. I typed out all of this... its a mixture of videos and googled code. I've tried to run `set.seed` once before and it runs, and when I run the summary it goes through, however, I'm not showing the results it's supposed to. I've tried to run `set.seed = 101` argument, I get a `Warning message: Number of logged events: 9`. When i do the summary, it doesn't list "rf" under the 3 columns I need to run & impute under. so I know the `set.seed` didn't work.

Comment: @JulieRae; there is a lot of text there. Is it correct that your query begins at the "*Use mice function*" section and it is that the function `mice` thows an error . If so, its worth deleting all the stuff before to make your question clearer. Have you tried restarting R and running again --> without loading a previous workspace? Can you edit your question with the results of `sessionInfo()` please. If the error persists in a fresh session can you share an example of `data` please - just enough to replicate the issue.

Comment: ... or do you also get the error with the built in datasets e.g. `imputed_data <- mice(nhanes2, m = 5, method = "rf")` .. in a fresh R session

Comment: I see, thank you for editing, that makes more sense and to the point. Sorry, I'm still learning. Not a built-in dataset. I imported the data. I've ran this code in both R-studio the new updated version, and in an R-kernel in jupyter-lab.  Both gave me the same error. When I do put the `set.seed` argument and then run the `summary`, it runs but shows that the random forest did not run in the columns I wanted it too. All the columns show up blank with no specifications that "rf" ran on those specific columns with missing data in the output.

Comment: Have you tried to initialize the .Random.seed? A possible solution should be to include the command:
`runif(1)`